# appium screen recording feature

Tags: ruby, rspec, appium-ios

I am trying to record the screen and referring to the following tutorial.

http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/device/recording-screen/start-recording-screen/

I tried the following piece of code but it doesn't save anything at this path.

`@driver.start_recording_screen video_type: 'h264', time_limit: '260', remote_path: '/recordings'`

I am putting it in `before` method so that it records everything for all the following 5 tests that I have in the particular spec file

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

To start recording use the below c# code:

```
driver.StartRecordingScreen(AndroidStartScreenRecordingOptions
.GetAndroidStartScreenRecordingOptions()
.WithTimeLimit(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
.EnableBugReport());
```

And then, to stop the recording, you need to use the following code. Since it creates recording in base64 format, you need to decode it to view.

```
String video = driver.StopRecordingScreen();
byte[] decode = Convert.FromBase64String(video);
                      
String fileName = "VideoRecording_test.mp4";
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, decode);
```

Comment: This doesn't look like `rspec`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to start the recording, we just need to call the `start_recording_screen` method from the respective classes.

```
before(:all) or before(:each) do
    @driver.start_recording_screen video_quality: 'low'
end
```

For IOS, please install ffmpeg (`brew install ffmpeg`).

We can add screen recording configurations like time limit, video size etc during the start of your video recording.

In order to stop the recording, we need to call the `stop_recording_screen` method from the respective classes.

Now, coming to the most important question! Where is our video?
The stopRecordingScreen() method returns a Base64 String. Using this string we need to build our video. There are many ways to do it, I have used decode64 method from Ruby Base64 module.

```
after(:all) do
    record = @driver.stop_recording_screen
    File.open('sample.mp4', 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(Base64.decode64(record))
    end
end
```

Finally you could find the recording under `sample.mp4`. I would recommend to play the video by VLC or Mplayer if you can not play the video with other video players.